# issue with hubble-pi camera capture

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have recently tried to install and get working a program developed to use with a telescope. It is called hubble-pi and can be found here. https://github.com/RemovedMoney326/Hubble-Pi

The program runs but when i click the capture button I get this issue. I have reached out to the dev but he has not replied and that was over a month ago. If anyone could assist in figuring out a solution that be awesome.

Im a beginner when it comes to python so be easy. This is also happening on boot up as this is the first thing im doing when turning on my RPI. I am running this on a RPI 4 2gb.

```
Python 3.7.3 (/usr/bin/python3)
>>> %Run AstroCam.py
Start
Capture
mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/AstroCameraApp/PythonScripts/AstroCam.py", line 60, in camHandler
    camera.resolution = DynamicCaptureResolution    #set photo size
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 2282, in _set_resolution
    self._enable_camera()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 1976, in _enable_camera
    self._camera.enable()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/mmalobj.py", line 724, in enable
    prefix="Failed to enable component")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/exc.py", line 184, in mmal_check
    raise PiCameraMMALError(status, prefix)
picamera.exc.PiCameraMMALError: Failed to enable component: Out of resources
```

Comment: We aren’t a stand-in for developer support. I believe this to be well off topic per the scope of the site defined in the [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 0):

I just hit this same error with another Picamera IMX477 app, and found a fix.

Set `gpu-mem=192` in `/boot/config.txt`, reboot, and 4032x3040 starts working.

This is for Pi-4, 2GB running Buster. Bullseye is a different animal.